# Customizing the index.php path in .htaccess - for routing to Zend Framework

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

First I apologies posting similar questions in this forum which already have 1000 or more similar topics. Unfortunately I couldn't yet find a solution so I thought it is worth posting here.

My issue:

We have Zend Framework installed in our web server and all non-file, non-directory requests are routed into index.php as follows:

> application
>
> httpdocs
>
> ```
> index.php
> ```

Our .htaccess file (in our public httpdocs folder) hold the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This works perfectly. However, for security purposes, I know want to move index.php to another sub-folder, so everything must be sent to my subfolder/index.php

> httpdocs
>
> ```
> subfolder
>
>     index.php
> ```

We tried the above and it worked successfully for all requests *except the home page*. It was done as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ subfolder/index.php [NC,L]
```

My home page is not loading, it's having a limitless redirect problem.

Could anyone kindly please help me on this situation?

I believe it is because going to www.mydomain.com causes Apache to look for an "index.html" first. When this file is not found, it looks for an "index.php". Previously, my index.php was in the web root - so this line worked:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

However now, there is no index.php there - it has moved to the subfolder. So this line should now work:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ subfolder/index.php [NC,L]
```

However, the problem is that that file isn't loading. The unlimited redirect tells me that htaccess keeps redirecting to itself and doesn't actually reach the subfolder/index.php file

Can anyone advise what I should do to make this work, or to test further?

A background to this ticket: we have been advised by security experts that it would be best to "limit" which folders can run PHP. Since index.php is in the root, we would rather move this to a sub folder so that only that sub folder can run PHP, and not the root itself. There are more details here but if anyone has any advise/questions/opinions please shout.

Many thanks!